# Forward an email using rest api and powershell (Azure Automation)

Tags: api, powershell

I'm trying to forward emails with attachments to a specific email address via Azure Automation (with message ID). I get the error message at the bottom after I run the code. I'm not really sure am I on the right track here (both with email sending and sending of attachments). Perhaps there's a better way to do this.
Could anyone lend a hand?

```
$credObject = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name "Myscreds"

$url = "https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/AAMkADA1MTAAAH5JaL/forward"

$body = "{
""Message"":{
 ""Subject"": ""This is a test"",
 ""Importance"": ""Low"",
 ""Body"": {
 ""ContentType"": ""HTML"",
 ""Content"": ""This is great!""
 },
 ""ToRecipients"": [
 {
 ""EmailAddress"":{
  ""Address"": ""myname@test.com""
  }
 }
 ]
 }}"

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Post -Credential $credobject -ContentType "application/json" -Body $Body
```

I get the following error message:

Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
At line:24 char:1
+ Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Post -Credential $credobject -Con ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], 
WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Per the [Microsoft documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations#forward-new-or-drafted-messages), you need to modify your request.

```
https://outlook.office.com/api/v1.0/me/messages/AAMkAGE0Mz8DmAAA=/forward
```

It looks like you forgot to include `/messages/` in your request.

However, it looks like you want to change the body of a message when you forward it.  This is more complicated, and you need to follow this workflow instead:

> Alternatively, if you need to modify any updateable properties in the message to be forwarded, you can first [create a draft forward message](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations#CreateForwardDraft), u[pdate the message properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations#UpdateMessages), and then send the reply.

Here's how that would look.

First, make a Draft of the message you want to forward

```
$request = "https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/messages/AAMkADA1MTAAAH5JaL/createforward"
$body = {
  "ToRecipients":[
 {
 ""EmailAddress"":{
  ""Address"": ""myname@test.com""
  }
 }
 ],
  "Comment": "Your sample message here" 
}
```

The response back is going to include some properties, including the ID of the new message.  You then use that to edit the Draft (to change the subject, etc) and then send it off.  Let me know if you need any further help.

Comment: Hi FoxDeploy, thank you firstly.

I don't think I was clear enough. I need to forward messages with attachments from a particular mailbox.

My thoughts were that I'd first get the message ID from the mailbox for that particular mail and then forward the message with the attachment. 
I don't need to change the body of the message, just a simple forward with attachment.

Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I had the incorrect message ID, that was my main problem. It's all resolved. I can forward messages with attachments using the message ID. Thanks again.

```
$credObject = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name "mycreds"


$url = "https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/Users('it-test@test.com')/messages/ASHJFKHFUISDFWIzLT=/forward"

$body = "{
 ""Comment"": ""A mail with some attachments (hopefully)"",
 ""ToRecipients"": [
 {
 ""EmailAddress"":{
  ""Address"": ""myname@test.com""
  }
 }
 ]
 }"

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Post -Credential $credobject -ContentType "application/json" -body $body
```